# Attach oninput event to textbox which you are creating dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic-controls

I have a `textbox` which has `oninput` event. It is working absolutely fine. Now, I am creating a `textbox` dynamically using `jQuery`, `textbox` is working fine but the event is not working. Following is my code:

```
row.append('<td> <input type="number" min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"  />');
```

This part `(value='')` is not working fine. I tried to use 0 instead of `''` and it worked. There is a`n unexpected token exception`. How can I solve it?

Comment: cause that would be two strings `'<td> <input type="number" min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='` and `');"  />'`

Comment: escape with \ like this `(value=\'\')`

Comment: Yes, I need to escape the character. Worked.